# Search for AWS Ami ID in all Regions in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ID for an AMI, but I don't know which region it's in.

Is there a way (in the AWS Console) to search across all regions to locate the AWS Region?

Or is it necessary to write a script that enumerates all regions and makes the query, such as [How to find AWS region of AMI with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021038/how-to-find-aws-region-of-ami-with-python)

Comment: Is it a public AMI? If so, I just use Google -- it normally manages to find a reference to the AMI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Tag Editor](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources) to search across all regions.